# Python Keras ValueError NeuralNetwork FlappyBird Game

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I cloned the following `Flappy-Bird` project (https://github.com/yanpanlau/Keras-FlappyBird) involving `reinforcement learning` locally in my pc. I installed the dependencies, but when I run it (`python qlearn.py -m "Run"`), I received the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skimage/viewer/__init__.py:6: UserWarning: Viewer requires Qt
  warn('Viewer requires Qt')
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Using TensorFlow backend.
Now we build the model
We finish building the model
Now we load weight
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qlearn.py", line 198, in <module>
    main()
  File "qlearn.py", line 195, in main
    playGame(args)
  File "qlearn.py", line 189, in playGame
    trainNetwork(model,args)
  File "qlearn.py", line 85, in trainNetwork
    model.load_weights("model.h5")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2701, in load_weights
    self.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 2787, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1544, in batch_set_value
    assign_op = x.assign(assign_placeholder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 575, in assign
    return state_ops.assign(self._variable, value, use_locking=use_locking)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 47, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2242, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1617, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1568, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 8 and 32 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [8,8,80,32], [32,4,8,8].
```

By default, Keras uses `tensorflow` as backend, so maybe the order of paramters can imply this error, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saved model is trained with `"image_dim_ordering": "th"`. I am pretty sure on your system currently its configured to `tf`. Just open `~/.keras/keras.json` and change it to `th` and the model should load properly.